# Writing my own image importer, pictures are not recognized as pictures after import

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

i am writing my own image import for my product catalog. I want to read the images from the local filesystem and store them in the configured assets folder. The import is very simple for now. Its one controller in the admin project and i trigger it by calling an url.

It is creating the files along with the folder structure and the files seem to have the same filesize, but somehow they get messed up along the way and they are not readable as images anymore (picture viewers wont open them). Any ideas why its being messed up ?

here the code:

```
@Controller("blImageImportController")
@RequestMapping("/imageimport")
public class ImageImportController extends AdminAbstractController {

    @Value("${image.import.folder.location}")
    private String importFolderLocation;

    @Resource(name = "blStaticAssetService")
    protected StaticAssetService staticAssetService;

    @Resource(name = "blStaticAssetStorageService")
    protected StaticAssetStorageService staticAssetStorageService;

    @RequestMapping(method = {RequestMethod.GET})
    public String chooseMediaForMapKey(HttpServletRequest request,
                                       HttpServletResponse response,
                                       Model model
    ) throws Exception {
        File imageImportFolder = new File(importFolderLocation);
        if (imageImportFolder.isDirectory()) {
            Arrays.stream(imageImportFolder.listFiles()).forEach(directory ->
            {
                if (directory.isDirectory()) {
                    Arrays.stream(directory.listFiles()).forEach(this::processFile);
                }

            });
        }
        return "";
    }

    private void processFile(File file) {
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            HashMap properties = new HashMap();
            properties.put("entityType", "product");
            properties.put("entityId", file.getParentFile().getName());
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            StaticAsset staticAsset = this.staticAssetService.createStaticAsset(fis, file.getName(), file.length(), properties);
            this.staticAssetStorageService.createStaticAssetStorage(fis, staticAsset);
            fis.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        } finally {
            try {
                if (fis != null)
                    fis.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a check in the `StaticAssetService` to try to detect this as an image (see https://github.com/BroadleafCommerce/BroadleafCommerce/blob/b55848f/admin/broadleaf-contentmanagement-module/src/main/java/org/broadleafcommerce/cms/file/service/StaticAssetServiceImpl.java#L217-L220). If it detected this correctly, you should get back an `ImageStaticAssetImpl` in the result to that call.

The flipside of this is the controller that actually reads the file (the `StaticAssetViewController` that renders a `StaticAssetView`). One of the things that the `StaticAssetView` does is set a response header for `mimeType` which the browser uses to render. This is set by this piece in the `StaticAssetStorageService`: https://github.com/BroadleafCommerce/BroadleafCommerce/blob/b55848f837f26022a620f0c2c143eed7902ba3f1/admin/broadleaf-contentmanagement-module/src/main/java/org/broadleafcommerce/cms/file/service/StaticAssetStorageServiceImpl.java#L213. I suspect that is the root of your problem.

Also just a note, sending those properties is not necessary when you are uploading the file yourself. That is mainly used in the admin when you are uploading an image for a specific entity (like a product or a category).

Comment: Ok i found the problem, the problem was that i use the same InputStream twice, once for `staticAssetService.createStaticAsset` and right after it for `staticAssetStorageService.createStaticAssetStorage`. Creating two different streams solves the problem. 

I use the properties so that i can attach the pictures to the products.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I was confused because in the `entityId` parameter you are using `file.getParentFile().getName()`. Usually this is the product id.

Comment: Hi phillip, i would like to add the images to the defaultSku, can you point me to the right direction ? From my understanding i need to create a SkuMediaXref and add it to the sku. But how do i get/create a Media object? I was looking in the Admin how its done there, but it seems i cant find the right controller.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply here. Yes, create a SkuMediaXref and add it to the skuMedia, setting both the `sku` property and `Media` property. For the `Media`, if you are doing it programmatically simply instantiate it with `new MediaImpl()` and set the `url` field. The `url` field can be anything (even an externally hosted image) but if you want it to link to a static asset, use `"/cmsstatic/" + staticAsset.getFullUrl()`. The `cmsstatic` part comes from `environment.getPropety("asset.server.url.prefix.internal")`.